# Возврат значения из Activity в Service

Tags: android

Как можно из сервиса запустить активити и получить из нее значение? Моя задача включает следующие ограничения:

1. `startActivityForResult()` не распространяется на сервисы, тем более функция - Deprecated. Здесь я Америку никому не открою.
2. Сервис вызывается извне, поэтому отказаться от него - не вариант.
3. Данные нужно получить в потоке выполнения сервиса. То есть из сервиса запустить активити, а потом из нее запустить сервис не подходит. В активити нужно заполнить некоторые значения и с ними вернуть управление сервису обратно, там же, где точка входа в него.
4. Целевая версия android - 6.0 (API 23).

Пока что выкрутился синхронизированным синглтоном с мапой внутри, но это тот еще велосипед.